# Transition color fade on hover?

Tags: css

I am trying to get this `h3` to fade on hover. Can someone help me out?

HTML

```
<h3 class="clicker">test</h3>
```

CSS

```
.clicker {
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-in;
    background:#f5f5f5;padding:20px;
}

.clicker:hover{
    background:#eee;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean invisible by `fade`?

Comment: I just want it to fade from #f5f5f5 to #eee

Answer (score 118, accepted):

What do you want to fade? The `background` or `color` attribute?

Currently you're changing the background color, but telling it to transition the color property. You can use `all` to transition all properties.

```
.clicker { 
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    background: #f5f5f5; 
    padding: 20px;
}

.clicker:hover { 
    background: #eee;
}
```

Otherwise just use `transition: background .2s ease-in`.

Answer (score 3):

For having a trasition effect like a highlighter just to highlight the text and fade off the bg color, we used the following:

```css
.field-error {
    color: #f44336;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: small;
    background-color: white;
}

.highlighter {
    animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /***Transition delay 3s fadeout is class***/
    -moz-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadeoutBg {
    from { background-color: lightgreen; } /** from color **/
    to { background-color: white; } /** to color **/
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeoutBg { /* Firefox */
    from { background-color: lightgreen; }
    to { background-color: white; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeoutBg { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from { background-color: lightgreen; }
    to { background-color: white; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeoutBg { /* Opera */
    from { background-color: lightgreen; }
    to { background-color: white; }
}
```

```html
<div class="field-error highlighter">File name already exists.</div>
```