# Background Fade In On Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I'm trying to make my background fade in upon entering the website. I've tried several methods that does work. However, I'm just having trouble centering the background on different resolution. As you can currently see upon entering my website, whenever you resize your browser, the background would be in the middle at all times. Website: http://studi0.ml/ That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, yet still have the globe to be in the middle at all times. And my background is pure CSS. Keep in mind, I just started website designing. I've been trying to code for 2-3 weeks now.

```css
html,
body {
  background: url(http://studi0.ml/EzJsucI.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.0s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.75s 0.0s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.75s 0.0s linear;
  transition: background 0.75s 0.0s linear;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem since the globe is on the image, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the globe is on the image. However, on some codes, whenever you resize the browser size, the global would go to the right. If you e.g click on my website, and try to resize your browser, you can see that the whole background moves according to the browser size.

- Sorry if I'm not explaining so well, trying my best.

Comment: perhaps screenshots of good and bad behavior and the wanted result made in photoshop or something will help us understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend a different setup if you want a background image to fade in on page load. You can have a separate div in a different flow than the rest of your page and have it animate to an opacity of 1 on page load.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
    <div class="page-bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

.page-bg {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(http://studi0.ml/EzJsucI.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;

    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Of course you might need to add polyfills for the `animation` and `keyframes` declarations. *(i.e. `-moz-animation-name`, `-webkit-animation-name`, etc..)*

Here is a working example on [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/OFj6lgKdNA4usQx8K7pF/). I had to swap the image you used with one with a `https` link so there wouldn't be an issue loading it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! That is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated!

Comment: One question, sir. I'm wondering how can I make the fade in color black? I've tried doing that: background: #000 url(http://studi0.ml/EzJsucI.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
- Yet, no results :)
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean, fade in *from* a background color of black?

Comment: I guess so. I mean, if you notice upon entering the website. The color of the fade seems white. Is there a way to change that fade color to black or any other color other than white?
- Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh, then add `background-color: #000` to the `body` style.

Answer (score 1):

If we are trying just to fade bg-color  of a div, we can use:

```css
.field-error {
    color: #f44336;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: small;
    background-color: white;
}

.highlighter {
    animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /***Transition delay 3s fadeout is class***/
    -moz-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadeoutBg 3s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadeoutBg {
    from { background-color: lightgreen; } /** from color **/
    to { background-color: white; } /** to color **/
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeoutBg { /* Firefox */
    from { background-color: lightgreen; }
    to { background-color: white; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeoutBg { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from { background-color: lightgreen; }
    to { background-color: white; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeoutBg { /* Opera */
    from { background-color: lightgreen; }
    to { background-color: white; }
}
```

```html
<div class="field-error highlighter">File name already exists.</div>
```

Similarly you can achieve any style change in `from` and `to` sections like `color: green` to change the font-color to green, or if you want to use :

1) **Fade-in**: give `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`
2) **Fade-out**: give `opacity: 1` to `opacity: 0`

For Further details refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525787/1904479