# How to modernize the color of another block on css

Tags: css

For example i have:

```
#1 {color: rgb(150, 255, 0)}
```

How can i modernize this color for another block, like this:

```
#2 {color: rgb (100, 255, 0)}
```

So, i need -50 on x of rgb (x, y, z).
Here are another example:

```
#1 {color: rgb(100, 100, 0)}
#2 {color: rgb(50, 100, 0)}
#1 {color: rgb(200, 200, 0)}
#2 {color: rgb(150, 200, 0)}
```

Comment: modernize? You want to update the colour due to an event? What is the event?

Comment: [This post may be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350126/transition-color-fade-on-hover)

Comment: Not event. It's theme for Tumblr, where color for #1 is {RGBAccentColor}, and i need #2 color.